# Send ordered data from an array

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

How can I send ordered data from an array in Telegram Bot?

For example, I have `text1`,`text2`,`text3` in an array, 
but it sends them like `text3`, `text1`, `text2`, so not in the original order.

This is my code:

```
function sendAllText(msg, opts) {
   if (locale.keyboards[msg.text].text) {
      var i,j,tempstring;
      for (i=0,j=locale.keyboards[msg.text].text.length; i<j; i++) {
          tempstring = locale.keyboards[msg.text].text[i];
          bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, tempstring, opts);
      }
   }
}
```

The function is called like this:

```
sendAllText(msg, opts);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/blob/release/doc/api.md#TelegramBot+sendMessage), `sendMessage` returns a promise: with this you can know when the message has been sent and then send the next one, ...etc:

```
function sendAllText(msg, opts) {
   if (locale.keyboards[msg.text].text) {
      var i,j,tempstring, promise;
      promise = Promise.resolve();
      for (i=0,j=locale.keyboards[msg.text].text.length; i<j; i++) {
          tempstring = locale.keyboards[msg.text].text[i];
          promise = promise.then(bot.sendMessage.bind(bot,msg.chat.id, tempstring, opts));
      }
   }
}
```

Alternatively, you could just join all the messages into one, and only send the combined message.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version of trincot's answer, trying to improve readability.

```
function sendAllText(msg, opts) {
  var textArr = locale.keyboards[msg.text].text;
  var promise = Promise.resolve();

  if (textArr.length) {
    textArr.forEach(function(value) {
      promise.then(function() {
        bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, value, opts);
      });
    });
  }
}
```